# Tab ColorIndex reset excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, colors, tabs

I wrote a VBA script which changes color of sheet tab in function of cells value.
The script runs well when I put the value, but when I clear the contents value of the cell, the script has failure and the color tab is not reset.

Script on Thisworkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("BH37")) Is Nothing Then
    Call CouleurOnglet(Sh, Target)
End If
End Sub
```

Script on module:

```
Sub CouleurOnglet(Sh As Object, Target As Range)
With Sh
    Select Case Target
    Case Is = "OK"
        .Tab.ColorIndex = 4 'Couleur verte
    Case Is = "NOK"
        .Tab.ColorIndex = 3 'Couleur rouge
    Case Is = "A vérifier"
        .Tab.ColorIndex = 45 'Couleur orange
    Case Else
        .Tab.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'reset couleur
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default color of the tab is no color which in ColorIndex has value -4142 or `xlcolorindexnone`.

If you put instead of:

```
.Tab.Color = xlAutomatic
```

the code:

```
.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
```

it should work as desired.

Comment: Nice, so we may also go through `.ColorIndex `. Thought we must go through `.Color` that's why I removed my answer, althoug I prefer the `.Color` option which seems more natural.